# Can't click on the first suggestion or first value

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to scrape the data from the website

> http://www.lacoteimmo.com/prix-de-l-immo/location/pays/france.htm#/.

I'm struggling to click on the first suggestion. I managed this code as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import time
import csv
import unittest
import sys
import datetime
import os.path
import pandas as pd

from geopy.geocoders import GoogleV3
from datetime import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import NavigableString
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import Tag
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.remote.errorhandler import ErrorHandler

def main(self):
CITIES = ["La Rochelle"]
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver=self.driver
ID=1
for city in CITIES:
print str(city) +" , "+str(ID)
ID+=1
try:
driver.get("http://www.lacoteimmo.com/prix-de-l-immo/location/pays/france.htm#/")
driver.implicitly_wait(30) 
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#mapAutosuggest").send_keys(city) # Enter city
# Wait until autosuggestion come and click on first suggestion
condition = EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#mapAutosuggest + span > span:nth-child(1)'))
WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(condition).click()
driver.implicitly_wait(50) 
except NoSuchElementException: #spelling error making this code not work as expected
pass
self.driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you send the character sequence **La Rochelle** next to click on the first suggestion you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("http://www.lacoteimmo.com/prix-de-l-immo/location/pays/france.htm#/")
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#mapAutosuggest").send_keys("La Rochelle") # Enter city
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.slam-aui-results>span.slam-aui-results-line.focus"))).click()
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: La Rochelle]

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
from geopy.geocoders import GoogleV3
from datetime import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import NavigableString
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import Tag
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.remote.errorhandler import ErrorHandler
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

CITIES = ["La Rochelle"]
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
# chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path='chrome_driver_path'
    , chrome_options=chrome_options
)

ID=1
for city in CITIES:
    print(str(city) + " , " +str(ID))
    ID+=1

try:
    driver.get("http://www.lacoteimmo.com/prix-de-l-immo/location/pays/france.htm#/")
    driver.implicitly_wait(30) 
    driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#mapAutosuggest").send_keys(city) # Enter city
    # Wait until autosuggestion come and click on first suggestion
    condition = EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.slam-aui-results > span:nth-child(1)'))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(condition)
    firstResult = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".slam-aui-results > span:nth-child(1)")
    firstResult.click()
    time.sleep(10)
    driver.implicitly_wait(50) 
except NoSuchElementException: #spelling error making this code not work as expected
    pass
driver.quit()
```